# Parent component that can get different components

Tags: reactjs

I have a `<Panel/>` component that has to get different changing components.

For example one time- the `<Panel/>` needs to contain a `<Dropdown/>` component, a second time a `<TextInput/>` and in the third time a `<Checkbox/>`.

How can I make this `<Panel/>` component to get different components?

The `<Panel/>` component:

```
import React from "react";
import { css } from "emotion";
import colors from '../../styles/colors';
import PanelHeader from "./PanelHeader";

export default function Panel({ active, panelHeader}) {
    const styles = css({
        borderRadius: 4,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        border: `1px solid ${ active ? colors.blue : colors.grayLight }`,
        width: 540,
        padding: 32,

    });
    return (
        <div className={styles}>
            {panelHeader && <PanelHeader headerType={panelHeader} />}
        </div>
    );
}
```

The Panel story:

```
import React from "react";
import { storiesOf } from "@storybook/react";

import Panel from "../components/Panel";
import colors from '../styles/colors';

import PanelHeader from "../components/Panel/PanelHeader";

storiesOf("Panel", module)
    .add("Default", () => (
        <Panel></Panel>
    ))
    .add("Active", () => (
        <Panel active></Panel>
    ))

storiesOf("Panel/PanelHeader", module)
    .add("Default", () => (
        <PanelHeader headerType="Identity document" color={colors.gray}>1</PanelHeader>
    ))
    .add("Active", () => (
        <PanelHeader headerType="Identity document" color={colors.blue}>1</PanelHeader>
    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `Panel` to accept `children` prop, pass it where you Render `<Panel>` and pass in the corresponding component.

For example:

```
// PropType for children is `PropTypes.node`
export default function Panel({ active, panelHeader, children}) {
    // ...
    return (
        <div className={styles}>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}

// ...

<Panel><Dropdown /></Panel>

// or

<Panel><TextInput /></Panel>
```

Or, you could pass in a component class/function and render it inside:

```
export default function Panel({ active, panelHeader, ChildComponent}) {
    // ...
    return (
        <div className={styles}>
            {/* This is like any other component, 
                you can pass in props as usual. */}
            {/* It's important for the name to start with an uppercase letter, 
                otherwise the JSX compiler will turn this in a string! */}
            <ChildComponent />
        </div>
    );
}

// ...

<Panel ChildComponent={Dropdown}></Panel>

// or

<Panel ChildComponent={TextInput}></Panel>
```

This pattern is called component composition. You can read more in React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: Great, thanks for the well explained answer, is the second option more recommended/professional?

Comment: @user3378165 The first one is more simple and easy to use and it's easier to understand the code. The second is more flexible as it allows you to pass custom component to render, but it usually makes the code a bit more complex. They are not entirely interchangeable, it depends on how you want to use it. I usually try to use the first approach where possible, because I strive to always write understandable code. Where that approach is not possible, I use the second one or [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).